# where does Activity class is instantiated in android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Complete novice to android. I was going through android activity life-cycle and wondering where does Activity class is instantiated?

Comment: This is done by the operating system. You do not have to worry about where it is initiated unless you want to delve into the technicalities of an operating system. However, Android uses an intent system to identify which activity or service to instantiate. This means Activities are instantiated the moment an intent is called for that activity. That "when/where" is known as context.

Comment: Thats great.Thank you :)